# Conflict between 2 .xsd files of the same SOAP Service

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a webservice, and I'm trying to write a client for it. But when I try to add a "Web Service Client" in Netbeans IDE, wsimport utility cannot parse the .wsdl. The reason is "The class serviceCompany is already in use".

I began to analyze the wsdl file, and noticed that there are 2 .xsd files related to the WS.

```
<types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://services.ws.x.net/" schemaLocation="https://test.x:443/PaymentWS/PaymentWS?xsd=1"/>
  </xsd:schema>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://commonws.ws.x.net/" schemaLocation="https://test.x:443/PaymentWS/PaymentWS?xsd=2"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

And I have a complex type named "ServiceCompany" inside of each .xsd files.

inside ?xsd=1:

```
<xs:complexType name="serviceCompany">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="bankAccount" type="tns:iban"/>
    <xs:element name="code" type="tns:companyCode"/>
    <xs:element name="description" type="tns:stringMax32"/>
    <xs:element name="taxNumber" type="tns:taxNumber"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

inside ?xsd=2:

```
<xs:complexType name="serviceCompany">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="code" type="cmn:companyCode"/>
    <xs:element name="description" type="cmn:stringMax32"/>
    <xs:element name="manualPaymentReceiverCode" type="cmn:companyCode" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="scCategoryList" type="cmn:stringMax32" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="status" type="cmn:objectStatus"/>
    <xs:element name="branchList" type="tns:serviceCompanyBranch" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The namespaces of there .xsd files are different, why wsimport cannot import the wsdl? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!